# Segmentation fault (code dumped) error in C

Tags: c, file, terminal, segmentation-fault, void

I was trying to run this code and it is saying "Segmentation fault (code dumped)" how I can fix my code to make this error go away. here is my code so if someone could help me out that would be awesome! How can i fix my void SEARCH

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct _data {
    char *name;
    long number;
};
int SCAN(FILE *(*stream)){
    int count = 0;
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), *stream)) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
struct _data*  BlackBoxLOAD(FILE **stream, int size){
    struct _data* BlackBox = (struct _data*)malloc(sizeof(struct _data)*size);
    int count = 0;
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), *stream)) {
        char* token = strtok(line, " ");
        struct _data* temp = (struct _data*)malloc(sizeof(struct _data));
        temp->name = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        temp->number = atoi(token);
        BlackBox[count] = *temp;
        count++;
    }
    return BlackBox;
}
void SEARCH(struct _data *BlackBox, char *string, int size){
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++){
        if (strcmp(BlackBox[i].name, string) == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
void FREE(struct _data *BlackBox, int size){
    free(BlackBox);
    return;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 0, size = 0;
    FILE *stream = fopen("hw5.data", "r");
    int noOfLines = SCAN(&stream);
    size = noOfLines;
    struct _data *BlackBox = BlackBoxLOAD(&stream, size);
    fclose(stream);
    for (i = 1; i<argc; i++){
        if (argv[i] == "") {
            printf("*******************************************");
            printf("* You must include a name to search for. *");
            printf("*******************************************");
        }
        int pos = SEARCH(BlackBox, argv[i], size);
        if (pos == -1) {
            printf("*******************************************");
            printf("The name was NOT found.");
            printf("*******************************************");
        }
        else{
            printf("*******************************************");
            printf("The name was found at the %d entry.", pos);
            printf("*******************************************");
        }
    }
    FREE(BlackBox, size);
}
```

Comment: Did you try punching "segmentation fault" into your favorite search engine?

Comment: This is some interestingly complex code for someone who doesn't know what a seg fault is.

Comment: It is not "code dumped" but "*core* dumped", see [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html); so basically compile your program with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use `gdb yourprog core`

Answer (score 0):

After the following line has been executed

```
int noOfLines = SCAN(&stream);
```

`stream` is at the end of the file. You need to rewind it before you can read the data. Add the line:

```
frewind(stream);
```

after the call to `SCAN`.

As an aside, you should change the argument type of `SCAN` and `BlackBoxLOAD` to `FILE*`.

```
int SCAN(FILE *stream){

struct _data*  BlackBoxLOAD(FILE *stream, int size){
```

That will make the calls easier and the functions don't have to dereference `stream`.

Function definition:

```
int SCAN(FILE *stream){
    int count = 0;
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stream)) {
                                     // Just stream, not *stream

        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Function call:

```
int noOfLines = SCAN(stream);
                     // Just stream, not &stream.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are just way too many bugs in this code, but here's the most obvious:

```
    char* token = strtok(line, " ");
    struct _data* temp = (struct _data*)malloc(sizeof(struct _data)*1000);
    temp->name = token;
```

You're setting `temp->name` to the value of `token`. But `token` points into `line`, which is getting modified and will soon cease to exist because you created it on a stack that's about to go away.

You can't save a pointer to a chunk of memory that you're about to reuse.